# Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data)

Tags: r, fault

I'm attempting to use the `CausalImpact` package in `R`. When I call the function I get an:

> "Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    invalid term in
>   model formula"

Which is too generic to be able to resolve. Anyone got any tips for trying to triage what's going on?

Thanks

**Edit**

I've included the code:

```
impact <- CausalImpact(na.omit(testdata_pivot[, 2:20]), c(1, 77), c(78, 301))
```

But I suspect it doesn't give a lot to go on. This question is really about how, when faced with a generic error message like the above, I should go about trying to isolate where the problems lies?

Comment: You should post your code, so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I, for one, use `traceback` and `browser` function. The script below generates:

```
Error in na.omit.ts(data[, 1:3]) : time series contains internal NAs
```

Script:

```
library(CausalImpact)
set.seed(123)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 52)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(52)
y[41:52] <- y[41:52] + 10
z <- 2 * y + rnorm(52)
z[22] <- NA
data <- cbind(y, x1, z)
str(data)
impact <- CausalImpact(na.omit(data[, 1:3]), c(1, 40), c(41, 52))
```

Then if you type in:

```
traceback()
```

The following call stack appears:

```
14: stop("time series contains internal NAs")
13: na.omit.ts(data[, 1:3])
12: na.omit(data[, 1:3])
11: xor(!is.null(data) && !is.null(pre.period) && !is.null(post.period) && 
        is.null(bsts.model) && is.null(post.period.response), is.null(data) && 
        is.null(pre.period) && is.null(post.period) && !is.null(bsts.model) && 
        !is.null(post.period.response))
10: eval(assertion, env)
9: eval(assertion, env)
8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
5: tryCatch({
       eval(assertion, env)
   }, assertError = function(e) {
       structure(FALSE, msg = e$message)
   })
4: see_if(..., env = env, msg = msg)
3: assert_that(xor(!is.null(data) && !is.null(pre.period) && !is.null(post.period) && 
       is.null(bsts.model) && is.null(post.period.response), is.null(data) && 
       is.null(pre.period) && is.null(post.period) && !is.null(bsts.model) && 
       !is.null(post.period.response)), msg = paste0("must either provide data, pre.period, post.period, ", 
       "model.args; or bsts.model and post.period.response"))
2: FormatInputForCausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period, model.args, 
       bsts.model, post.period.response, alpha)
1: CausalImpact(na.omit(data[, 1:3]), c(1, 40), c(41, 52))
```

You identified that some problem with `na.omit.ts` (It was not good idea to introduce `NA` into time series).

Then I create dummy function and add `browser()` into its body:

```
test <- function() {
  browser()
  CausalImpact(na.omit(data[, 1:3]), c(1, 40), c(41, 52))
}
```

When I run test() I'm going into debug mode. And can do all the debugging I want (inspect variables, change some code, enter into function, skip lines etc.). You can type `help` in debug mode for more options.